# How to change link depending on div id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Jcink Forums - I can style divs based on the user group which can be used as a html variable (for IDs).

How can I change the link based on the ID?

I'm assuming this cannot be done via just css and html however I'm not well-versed in JS

For Example (not the full code, just a really abridged version):

Stylesheet:

```css
#admin .avatar {background-image:url("admin.jpg");}
#mod .avatar {background-image:url("mod.jpg");}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="<!-- |g_id| -->">
    <a href="link changes based on div id">
        <div class="avatar"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: add your desired link with semple with div id so we will go ahead on this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you want to change the link based on ID? Surely JCink provides the correct link? I can't help but feel there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: does the id of div change with time, or you are adding multiple div, with different id's, please specify

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? What is the change based on the `id` at HTML? Is the `id` a valid URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can script, you can do something like (inline for demonstration, you can loop over all divs and change their links)

```
<div id="<!-- |g_id| -->">
  <a href="whatever" onclick="this.href=this.closest('div[id]').id=='xxx'?'zzz':'yyy'">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

where an ID of xxx will set the href to zzz otherwise set it to yyy

Comment: Thanks! This was the easiest and most flexible - much appreciated.

Comment: @KateBishop You are welcome. The more details you give the better answers we can give. I seem to have guessed correctly :)

Comment: maybe once I have it 100% coded out I'll return and update. I'm still wrapping my head around the complex (yeah, this is complex for me) stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAttribute to set the link href according to the id

```js
var ele=document.querySelectorAll("div");
Object.values(ele).forEach((e)=>{
if (e.getAttribute("id") == "abcd") {
  var link = e.querySelector("a");
  link.removeAttribute("href");
  link.setAttribute("href", "www.link2.com");
} 
})
```

```html
<div id="abcd">
  <a href="link1">
    <div class="avatar">aa</div>
  </a>
```

Comment: You selector assumes one div on the page but you are not necessarily changing the link in that div and also not choosing what link to give based on the div